# Framework user interface for running tests and reporting results

Tags: .net, testing, user-interface

I often have to create software to run tests (on hardware or other software), but I don't know of a good user interface control in .NET for displaying test results.

(Just to clarify, I am not looking for a testing solution for .NET code. I am looking for a way to provide a system similar to those used for testing code to a user so that she can run pre-made tests on some other object.)

Most unit testing frameworks provide such a user interface, and I am particularly fond of Resharper's UI for unit tests:
[image: Resharper's UI for tests]

Does anyone know of a custom control (open source or for purchase) that would provide this sort of interface?

Ideally, the developer would be able to load up the UI with a collection of items which can be `Run` and potentially `Stop`ped, would have a `Passed` boolean, and could output useful information (e.g. text or formatted HTML/XML).

Answer (score 0):

It's not a framework, but [Gallio](http://gallio.org/) is open source and has a nice GUI which could be adapted for this purpose.
[image: Gallio test runner GUI]

Another open source starting point could be [gtest-gbar](https://github.com/ospector/gtest-gbar):
[image: GUI for gtest-gbar]